# IE11 - performance issues when using app directly from a computer, but no issues when using it from a remote desktop connection on the same computer

Tags: performance, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, performance-testing, remote-desktop

I'm debugging an IE11 performance issue regarding this library https://github.com/tiberiuzuld/angular-gridster2

But I am unable to debug this issue, because I'm working from a remote desktop connection and everything runs smoothly while doing so.

Situation is as follows:

If I have connected from computer A to computer X with remote desktop connection, [this app](https://angular-7-registration-login-example-dd2z2s.stackblitz.io/login?returnUrl=%2F) runs smoothly on IE11.

If I am working directly on the computer X, [the same app](https://angular-7-registration-login-example-dd2z2s.stackblitz.io/login?returnUrl=%2F) in IE11, dragging the widgets around are dropping alot if frames and lagging insanely.

This just seems so mysterious to me, because I can't imagine why something would run smoother from a RDC. (The other way around would sound more believable).

What could be causing this? Is there anything I can do to make the RDC behave the same as working from the computer directly?

Answer (score 1):

Can't reproduce your problem, on my side, your app running result is same on current desktop and remote computer. I suggest you could open the task manager to check OS performance, and you could also try to clear the IE browser history.

If still not working, try to use [F12 developer tools for analytic performance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide/performance).

Comment: So does it lag on both or does it run smoothly on both?

Comment: Both on current desktop and remote computer, it is a little lag.